# Typeorm Insert Foreign Key by String

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

When user registers, I want to him to send his account name, so I will have "Accounts" table with reference to the user entity. I'm using Nest.js.
I'm looking for alternative to the following logic in my `users.service.ts` Register method:

1. Find Account by Name
2. If Account not found, Create It
3. Create User with the Account found above

Here is my Account Entity:

```
  @Entity()
  export class Account extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;
  
    @Column({ unique: true })
    name: string;
  
    @Column()
    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;
  }
```

And my User Entity:

```
@Entity() 
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Account, (Account) => Account.name, { cascade:true })
  @JoinColumn({name: 'name'})
  account: Account;
}
```

My CreateUserDTO:

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  account: string;
}
```

And this is the error when I try to do `User.create(dto)`:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Account | DeepPartial<Account>'.`

In addition, for some reason, the `User.create(dto)` returns array of users and not single user, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed like this :

```js
// create-user.dto.ts

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  accountName: string;
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    name: string; // This is your relations between user and account defined in JoinColumn decorator

    @ManyToOne(() => Account, (Account) => Account.name, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'name' })
    account: Account;
}
```

```js
// user.service.ts

// user.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Account)
        private readonly accountRepository: Repository<Account>, // Or your custom repository
        @InjectRepository(User)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<User> // Or your custom repository
    ) {}

    public async register(dto: CreateUserDto): Promise<void> {
        let accountToSaveWithUser: Account;
        // First check if account exist
        const account = await this.accountRepository.findOne({
            where: {
                name: dto.accountName,
            },
        });

        if (isNil(account)) {
            const accountToSave = this.accountRepository.create({
                name: dto.accountName,
            });
            accountToSaveWithUser = await this.accountRepository.save(accountToSave);
        } else {
            accountToSaveWithUser = account;
        }

        await this.userRepository.save({
            email: dto.email,
            password: hash(dto.password), // Use your package for hash password
            name: accountToSaveWithUser.name,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way without developing the creation/finding of the account.

Sounds like a pretty common use case (When you want to have a table with id + value only)